# Loop through array with set intervals

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

Lets say you have a simple array like

```
var someArray = ["1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9"];
```

Looping through the array like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(someArray[i]);
    };
```

gives this in the console......

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

....but is there a way of iterating through the array so that only nth items are selected?  For example, 3nth values would give in the console

```
1, 4, 7, ........
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.

Your for iterator is actually composed of 3 parts.  Declaration, condition and increment.

The increment is the 3rd parameter and most likely you've always just seen it as i++, but it can be anything.  In your example, you'd want to increment i by 3, so i += 3.

```
for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i += 3) {
    console.log(someArray[i]);
};
```

Comment: Awesome thanks @Scottie.  Yes I've always ever seen the increment part of the for iterator as i++.  I guessed it would be something so simple as that but never knew it could be anything

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple technique involving the use of the modulo operator. You may use the following loop to achieve this if you do not wish to change by how much you increment i:

```
var someArray = ["1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9"];

for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    if( i % 3 === 0 ){
         console.log(someArray[i]);
    }
}
```

You may want to do this if you have other operations to perform on each element but would also like to perform specific operations on nth elements. You may replace the number 3 in my example with any number you like to represent the nth element value.

Comment: Thanks @vullnetyy works perfectly!  What does the if condition actually mean though?  If i = 0 but increment by 3??

Comment: It divides i by 3 and checks if it is a multiple of 3. For instance 6 % 3 is equal 0 because in integer division 3*2+0=6 but 7 is 3*2+1=0 so 7 % 3 is actually equal to 1.

Comment: @DMH technically the modulo operator outputs the remainder of the division of two numbers. So if you do 2 % 3 then the result is 2 because 0*3 + 2 = 2. The +2 here is the remainder which ends up being the result of the operation.

Comment: @vullnetyy I was explaining what the condition meant, knowing the result of the modulus operator is 3rd grade math and I don't think requires explanation. Also I believe it's obvious that if you divide 2 by 3 in integer division the remainder will be the result, again 3rd grade math.